# How to convert tensorflow file to tensorflow lite on windows

Tags: windows, tensorflow

I have a retrained_graph.pb file which I want to convert to tensorflow lite.I tried to do it with toco in Docker but it seems that there is no module such called toco in my system.I have the latest version of tensorflow installed.Can someone please tell me how to do it?
I am running on Windows 10 64bit

Answer (score 0):

I'm the community manager of Heartbeat (an online pub that looks at the intersection of mobile and ML. One of our contributors just published a tutorial that addresses this exact issue. Hope it's helpful!

https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/working-through-a-tensorflow-lite-tutorial-on-windows-10-e27ee0e8b8cc